# Swallow InterruptedException in ExecutorService or not?

Tags: java, executorservice, interrupted-exception

There is an article by IBM.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html?ca=drs-#2.1

This says never swallow interruptedException. The same thing is there on sonar.

"InterruptedException" should not be ignored.

But there is a question on StackOverflow regarding interruptedException inside Executorservice, which suggests, we should not set the interrupt again.
[InterruptedException inside ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364224/interruptedexception-inside-executorservice)

Is the IBM article is quite old, and does not take the modern Java Concurrent package into account?
How should we handle interruptedException in ExecutorService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a decision in all places you have trapped InterruptedException as it depends on the situation and importance for your code.

A sensible response is for your task is to take heed of the interrupt, to allow a graceful cancellation or shutdown of the current thread or Runnable within executor. There won't much point resetting `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in your outermost part of a Runnable (as thread will exit just afterwards, or Executor is managing that interrupt).

However if you are trapping that exception several layers of call stack below the task control then resetting `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` may help the higher levels of your task see and bail out gracefully - but only if they are checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` at each stage or your code passes on the InterruptedException or an application specific exception.

Comment: Hi @DuncG, if possible, could you please help me to understand "trapping that exception several layers of call stack below the task control". What exactly that means and what would be the  scenario when that happens in ExecutorService?

Comment: Say your Runnable A was a big loop, each time calling B. If you trapped IntExc in B then exited B without doing anything that told A of this situation, then A  would process next B call rather than bail out. So its your decision as to whether its appropriate for A to resumes loop or not - which could be by a flag or call interrupted() again or do nothing to let A resume

Comment: Thanks @DuncG for the reply. But my question was regarding ExecutorService. Suppose we have List of callable tasks.

tasks.add(() -> { return processSublist(subList);});

Each task is processing 100,000 numbers of records and we want to process 1 million records.
If there is some InterruptedException in calling executorService.invokeAll(tasks), should we reset Thread.currentThread().interrupt() or not? Or Is ExecutorService will take care of it?

Comment: The ExecutorService appears to reset the flag before running the next task so once your task is done the flag is cleared for the next task. I verified it in one of my programs by adding `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` at the end and  `System.out.println("START/END "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" isInterrupted="+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());` to start / end.